# How to exploit a buffer overflow to execute instructions on the stack

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm starting to tinker with buffer overflows, and wrote the following program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void g() {
  execve("/bin/sh", NULL, NULL);
}

void f() {
  long *return_address;
  char instructions[] = "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80"; // exit(1)

  return_address = (long*) (&return_address + 2);
  *return_address = (long)&g; // or (long)instructions
}

int main() {
  f();
}
```

It does what I expect it to do : `return_address` overwrite the return address of `f` with the address of `g`, which opens a shell. However, if I set the return address to `instructions`, I got a segmentation fault, and none of the instructions in `instructions` is executed.

I compile with GCC, using `-fno-stack-protector`.

How could I prevent this segmentation fault occurring ?

Comment: Not an expert, but could it be that `instructions` is saved in the data segment and therefore it trips the Data Execution Prevention (or its name under Linux) and therefore the program is terminated? If I understand correctly, this is not the same thing as a stack overflow, and it isn't disabled by `-fno-stack-protector`. But I'm not sure at all!

Comment: @FabioTurati ``instructions`` is stored in the stack, I've checked with GDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one problem isn't related to the buffer overflow.

```
execve("/bin/sh", NULL, NULL);
```

That first NULL becomes the argv of the process you're starting.  argv must be an array of strings that is *terminated* with a NULL.  So a segfault may happen when `/bin/sh` starts up, tries to read `argv[0]`, and dereferences NULL.

```
void g(void) {
    char *argv[] = { "/bin/sh", NULL };
    execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
}
```

You might also add `-z execstack` to the gcc command line, which will tell the linker to permit an executable stack.  You should also verify that the instructions you have there are what `exit(1)` compiles to on your system if you got them from a tutorial somewhere.